# canvas 2 фигуры заливаются одним и тем же цветом

Tags: javascript, canvas

Почему фигуры заливаются одним и тем же цветом?

```
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = "rgba(115,203,253,0.562)";
context.moveTo(175,115);
context.lineTo(175,130);
context.lineTo(625,130);
context.lineTo(650,115);
context.fill();
context.fillStyle = "rgba(225,203,253,1)";
context.moveTo(175,185);
context.lineTo(175,195);
context.lineTo(312,195);
context.lineTo(312,185);
context.fill();
context.closePath();
```

Comment: контур не замкнутый

Comment: добавь картинку, какой именно результат ты ожидаешь

Answer (score 4):

Вы пути не закрываете после рисования, не забывайте добавлять новый beginPath если начинаете новую фигуру или закрывающий closePath, когда закончили работу с фигурой.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = "rgba(115,203,253,0.562)";
context.moveTo(175,115);
context.lineTo(175,130);
context.lineTo(625,130);
context.lineTo(650,115);
context.fill();

context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = "rgba(225,203,253,1)";
context.moveTo(175,185);
context.lineTo(175,195);
context.lineTo(312,195);
context.lineTo(312,185);
context.fill();
context.closePath();
```

```css
canvas{
  outline: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="700px" height="400px"></canvas>
```